# Reset password on Azure VM scale set while extension exist

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I referred to below link and succeeded to reset password on VM scale set with extension created
[Reset password of a virtual machine scale set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737441/reset-password-of-a-virtual-machine-scale-set)

Now, I want to reset the password again. However, if I perform the same as above, it will give me an error during Update-AzVmss

```
Update-AzVmss: On resource 'VMSS1', extension name 'VMAccessAgent' cannot be used for more than one extension.
ErrorCode: BadRequest
ErrorMessage: On resource 'VMSS1', extension name 'VMAccessAgent' cannot be used for more than one extension.
ErrorTarget: 
StatusCode: 400
ReasonPhrase: Bad Request
OperationID : 53c2fea8-bf5a-47fe-a5e9-8e98eea1bb7b
```

How should I reset the password again? Does it mean I have to remove the extension and run the Powershell script again?

Answer (score 1):

The error you are referring(On VM Scale Set 'VMSS1', extension name 'VMAccessAgent' cannot be used for more than one extension), I suspect this could be related to this one:"Multiple VMExtensions per handler not supported for OS type '{0}'. VMExtension '{1}' with handler '{2}' already added or specified in input."

[Understand common error messages when you manage virtual machines in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/error-messages)

If the issue still persist, remove the extension and Process password update through script:

> $vmss = ""
>
> $vmssResourceGroup = ""
>
> $publicConfig = @{"UserName" = ""}
>
> $privateConfig = @{"Password" = ""}
>
> $extName = "VMAccessAgent"
>
> $publisher = "Microsoft.Compute"
>
> $vmss = Get-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName $vmssResourceGroup
> -VMScaleSetName $vmssName
>
> $vmss = Add-AzVmssExtension -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss -Name
> $extName -Publisher $publisher -Setting $publicConfig
> -ProtectedSetting $privateConfig -Type $extName -TypeHandlerVersion "2.0" -AutoUpgradeMinorVersion $true
>
> Update-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName $vmssResourceGroup -Name $vmssName
> -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to remove the extension using any PowerShell commands. Ultimately I just deleted it in the portal and then was able to set the extension.